# Determine "store Id" for a folder to use CLI to upload and list credentials

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using the [CloudBees Folders Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Folders+Plugin) with nested folders and the [Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin) for managing secrets into different pipeline jobs. Let's say I have a Jenkins folder structure like this.

```
folder1/
    folder2/
        job1
```

The folders plugin allows me to scope credential domains and credentials to folders, so that only jobs in those folders can access those credentials.

I can do this through the UI, but we rotate these credentials every so often and want to automate part of this.

One way we thought of doing this was to use the [Jenkins CLI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI).

There are various different commands provided by the credentials plugin here.
For example:

> **list-credentials** - Lists the Credentials in a specific Store
>
> java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ list-credentials
>   STORE
>
> Lists the Credentials in a specific Store
>
> **STORE** : Store ID

---

> **list-credentials-context-resolvers** - List Credentials Context Resolvers
>
> java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/
>   list-credentials-context-resolvers
>
> List Credentials Context Resolvers

---

> **list-credentials-providers**     - List Credentials Providers
>
> java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/
>   list-credentials-providers
>
> List Credentials Providers

---

The **STORE** for Jenkins global scope was determined by me by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/blob/e0d05e2103b9518588757b83543833f4c87465a1/src/test/java/com/cloudbees/plugins/credentials/cli/CLICommandsTest.java#L94), which shows it is `system::system::jenkins`.

If I run a few commands I can start to possibly extract some information:

```
✗ java -jar credential-management/build/jenkinsAutomation/Localhost/cli/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 list-credentials-context-resolvers --username admin --password password
```

Results in: [image: results of CLI command list-credentials-context-resolvers]

Running the following:

```
✗ java -jar credential-management/build/jenkinsAutomation/Localhost/cli/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 list-credentials system::system::jenkins --username admin --password password
```

Results in:
[image: results of CLI command list-credentials]

Now, I'm trying to list some credentials for a folder, and don't have a clue how to get the `STORE` (store Id indicated by the documentation).

I have tried

```
✗ java -jar credential-management/build/jenkinsAutomation/Localhost/cli/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 list-credentials folder::items::folder1 --username admin --password password
```

But receive *ERROR: The specified resolver folder::items::folder1 cannot be uniquely identified*:

[image: error when running trying to run list-credentials for folder]

How do I determine the `STORE` of a folder so that I can use the `create-credentials-by-xml` or other commands to automate them? Or, how can I just executed Groovy using the scripting support to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you are almost there.

Credentials Store ID format is `Provider::Resolver::ContextPath`

`Provider` name can be found with `list-credentials-providers` command. You correctly used `folder` here.

`Resolver` name can be found with `list-credentials-context-resolvers` command. I believe that is where you made a typo. It should be `item` not `items`.

`ContextPath` is `Resolver` dependent. In the case of `system` it can only be `jenkins`. In the case of `folder` it is a full path to the folder, e.g. `/folder1/subfolder1`.

Therefore, STORE argument in your last command should be `folder::item::/folder1`